# Flutter - How to display multiple images and pdf in a list view?

Tags: image, dart, listview, pdf

Inside a list are images and pdfs. I am having trouble in displaying them in flutter. I can only display one image but when I try to display multiple images/ images and pdfs, that is when I get an error message. `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Initializing list

```
List _babyList = List();
```

Here is the value of _babyList. I fetch it from the database and this is the value when I print it. print(_babyList);

```
[[https://brrtforce-uploads.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/609feb3289f7420015514b54/request-applicant/validId/yh215ikmcot51-1.jpg, https://brrtforce-uploads.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/609feb3289f7420015514b54/request-applicant/validId/breakout.jpg]]
```

Displaying multiple files in a listview.builder

```
    : ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _babyList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(_babyList[index]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
```

PS. what if the list consists of images and pdfs? How can I know the file type and display it in a list view?

Comment: What is the Image.network type that you are passing in the data to? Also, why are you not defining a type on your list?

Comment: The file inside the _babyList(). You can see the value after the print line code above.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to put a typed list

List _babyList = List();